# Skipping a review audit and clicking back show another user's results

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

So I was reviewing low quality posts last week when I came across one that I wasn't sure about so I skipped it. I went back in pages and found that the one I had skipped was actually a test. Here's what's strange: it shows the review failed and shows that it was another user failed it. It didn't dawn until me recently that this could be a bug. Should skipping a test and clicking back show me another user's results?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5372864

> [image]

Comment: Well, it is the same as following the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5372864). I don't think it is a bug, as it can be used to reference said audit (like on this exact case).