# Tried to edit in review queue, got redirected and saw another user's audit?

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

I was going through the first posts queue and clicked "edit" on one because it had odd formatting.

Before I submitted any edits, I opened the question in new tab to double check the context. I saw that the answer was posted almost a month ago, with positive score -- okay, it's an audit and I will probably fail if I try to submit an edit.

So I went back to editor tab and clicked "cancel".

Two weird things:

1. Clicking "cancel" then redirected me to the actual question page, instead of the review queue
2. I thought maybe I mixed up my tabs, but no, I go back two steps in my history to the review queue: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/14047496 - Congrats to AVK, but, uh, that's not me (and now I can't get my audit pass, boo)

Issue 2 appears to be the same behavior as in this question: [Skipping a review audit and clicking back show another user's results](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267243/skipping-a-review-audit-and-clicking-back-show-another-users-results), so let's set that aside for now.

Issue 1, on the other hand, I didn't find any posts about. Seems like a bug to me - cancelling should return me to the queue, not the question.

Comment: Audits are broken for folks without full editing rights. Need to ditch that queue.